# Combinatorics with $n$ distinct cards and $k$ people

Tags: combinatorics

Essentially, given $n$ distinct cards, how many hands can I deal to $k$ people such that everyone will have at least one card? I’ve done some searching and found this related to the Sterling numbers of the second kind. However, I don’t understand how these formulas were derived, specifically how does the formula account for scenarios where someone doesn’t have a card?

As an example, say I have 17 cards and 3 people. How many ways can I deal hands to everyone such that each person has at least one card?

Relevant Information:

[image]

Comment: You already have the formula. Why don't you just apply it?

Comment: [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) provides a nice way to think about this sort of counting.

Comment: @levent because I don’t understand it. I’d like to be able to explain it to someone who does not know.